# Java String.format with currency symbol

Tags: java, locale

There is some **existing code** of the follow form which is used for format numerical values:

```
String.format( pattern, value )
```

Note that I **cannot change the code itself** - I can only change the format pattern supplied to the code.

What is the format pattern to output a currency symbol for the default locale?  Essentially, I want to achieve the following output:

```
String.format( "...", 123 )  => $ 123
```

Comment: Maybe worth look at [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(long)).

Comment: edited to mention I cannot change the code

Comment: @MarcPolizzi: you can't change the code, but you *can* change the format string (presumably specified elsewhere) - is that right?

Comment: @Greg: sorry forgot to mention yes only the pattern itself.

Comment: I think it is not possible to change the currency symbol automatically. Code must be placed in hard-code.

Comment: In what way can you change the format string? Properties file via ResourceBundle, maybe?

Comment: @Urs : does not matter how I can change it no? Just need the "pattern" value to display the currency symbol of the JVM locale.

Comment: @Paul : please update your response saying it is not possible then I'll accept it - of course "euro" is an example.

Comment: It matters a lot, because if you had a mechanism that was inherently locale specific or at least supported locales, your problem could be solved through hard-coding the symbol in that mechanism.

Comment: @Urs : right but in that case my question would not exist ;-) You could reply this is not possible unless hardcoding the locale symbol into the pattern.

Comment: @Marc, note my answer for a possible alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the constraints you have given, I think it is impossible to achieve it.
To get to the current Locale's currency symbol, you'll need a minimum of code.

If you have absolutely no means to add code to the program, you'd best use the established symbol for "[currency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_%28typography%29)" (¤). It was established for this exact purpose, to symbolize currency absent any more specific symbol.

If you can't change the given code, but add code to the project as a whole, you can use that to find out the symbol best used. Once you have it, you can use it to create a pattern for the existing code to use for formatting.

If you can find out in which Locale the original program will run in next, you could write a assistant program that uses that setting to fill your configuration.

Answer (score 18):

No need to reinvent the wheel. [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) comes with currency support:

```
String output = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(123.45);
```

This also comes with full locale support by optionally passing in a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
String output = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format( 123.45);
```

Here's a test:

```
System.out.println(DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format( 123.45) );
System.out.println(DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format( 123.45)) ;
```

Output:

```
$123.45
123,45 €
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(" %d \u20AC", 123)); // %d for integer
    System.out.println(String.format(" %.2f \u20AC", 123.10)); // %f for floats
}
```

This prints:

```
123 €
123.10 €
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no default Locale available, we can go with setting the currency symbol using unicode and decimal formatting. As in the below code:

For e.g. Setting the Indian currency symbol and formatting the value. This will work without user making changes in the settings.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("\u20B9");
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(12324.13));
```

Output:

```
₹12,324.13
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    String formatstring=String.format("$%s", 123);
    System.out.println(formatstring);
```

Comment: Does not seems to print a EURO symbol if the local of my JVM is French; still display $

Comment: ohhh sorry . I thought you want to print $ .