# How to Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format in java

Tags: java, nslocale

current amount in UK format using Locale.UK and pattern #,##0.00 - 450,500.00
but i need it in Indian format

Comment: possibly duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826850/java-string-format-with-currency-symbol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format)

Answer (score 2):

try ICU4J available from Maven central repo

```
    Format format = com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
    String str = format.format(100000000);
```

output

```
10,00,00,000
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to you third party libraries you can try this code as well

`Format df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,000.00");
int val = 10000000;
System.out.println(df.format(val));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
public String getIndianCurrencyFormat(String amount) {
        
        String decimal = null;
        
        if(amount.contains(".")) {
            String[] array = amount.split("\\.");
            amount = array[0];
            decimal = "."+array[1];
        }
        
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        char amountArray[] = amount.toCharArray();
        int a = 0, b = 0;
        for (int i = amountArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (a < 3) {
                stringBuilder.append(amountArray[i]);
                a++;
            } else if (b < 2) {
                if (b == 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(",");
                    stringBuilder.append(amountArray[i]);
                    b++;
                } else {
                    stringBuilder.append(amountArray[i]);
                    b = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        
        
         
         if(decimal != null) {
                stringBuilder.reverse();
                return stringBuilder.append(decimal).toString();
          }else {
              return stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
          }
    }
```